# Regression for data that distribute logarithmic but not binary

Tags: regression

I want to preform a regression analysis with one independent variable (questionnaire score) and one dependent variable (range from 0-100). The dependent score is the problematic one- most participants receive either the score of 100 or 0, but some participants (not many) receive a score in between (e.g., 67). Therefore, the data is not binary. Can someone recommend a statistical method which fits this type of data?[image]

Comment: If you rescale the outcome to $[0,1]$ (on your graph you already have) then logistic regression might still work.  But you should only use it if the implicit model is theoretically justified

Comment: Look at fractional response models, for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172557/proportion-dependent-variable-0-1-range-in-an-unbalanced-non-dynamic-panel  and search this site.   A better link:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre